# How to speed up opening .png bitmaps on Android?

Tags: android

Welcome all

actually i'm opening png files from assets folder with this code:

```
public static Bitmap loadImage( String imageName ){
    if( imageName.charAt(0) == '/' ) {
        imageName = imageName.substring(1);
    }
    imageName = imageName + ".png";
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResourceAsStream(imageName));
    return image;
}
public static InputStream getResourceAsStream( String resourceName ) {
    if( resourceName.charAt(0) == '/' ) {
        resourceName = resourceName.substring(1);
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = context.getAssets().open( resourceName );
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return is;
}
```

This code opens the bitmaps with full cuality and it takes a lot of time to open it.

Also any sugerences to speed up the opening of the bitmap will be welcome

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the image size, setting how the image will be subsample on the moment it is loaded from file:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inSampleSize= 2; // When 2, the orignal width will be divided by 2, and the height too.
Bitmap bmSource = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opt);
```

If you need to load from a InputStream do that:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, opt);
```

Comment: If i do that, my bitmap haves the half size of the original PNG file? i need that the bitmap haves the same size... please tell me that

Comment: @AndroidUser99 Yes, half size. How large is your image? When I use the method decodeFile is always fast, even if I don't reduce the images.

Comment: @AndroidUser99 You can also try to pre-load the image before really needing it. It can be done in another Thread.